# how does iff or ?: evaluate series of boolean

Tags: pine-script

Hi i'm new with pine script i try to understand how iff or ?: evaluate series of boolean.

```
higher_than = high > close
x = higher_than ? 1 : 0
```

is `higher_than ?` here is eveluated as "any", if any value is true in the serie of data or it is evaluated as "all", if all data in series are true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of x will be calculated separately for each bar. That is, on those bars where high > close, the variable x = 1, and on those bars where high == close, the variable x = 0.

Comment: thank you for your answer it make things much clearer for me.
one more question, if i write this ```x = higher_than ?  high[2] : na```   its mean that each value with true is remplaced with high value at specific index ?

Comment: yes, it means that if higher_than==true on a current bar, the x variable will take the value high[2] (i.e. the value high for a bar that is 2 bars apart from the current one).